# Call a function from another package in Go

Tags: go

I have two files `main.go` which is under `package main`, and another file with some functions in the package called functions.

My question is: How can I call a function from `package main`?

**File 1: main.go (located in MyProj/main.go)**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "functions" // I dont have problem creating the reference here

func main(){
    c:= functions.getValue() // <---- this is I want to do
}
```

**File 2: functions.go (located in MyProj/functions/functions.go)**

```
package functions

func getValue() string{
    return "Hello from this another package"
}
```

Comment: You must start your function name with a capital name (`GetValue()`) in order to call it from outside.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You import the package by its import path, and reference all its exported symbols (those starting **with a capital letter**) through the package name, like so:

```
import "MyProj/functions"

functions.GetValue()
```

Comment: Thanks! PS. Could you include the example of the question in its correct form?

Comment: I don't understand how `MyProj` is defined/recognized

Comment: make sure you don't forget to Capitalize the function name so it can be exported.

Answer (score 22):

- You should prefix your import in `main.go` with: `MyProj`, because, the directory the code resides in is a package name by default in Go whether you're calling it `main` or not. It will be named as `MyProj`.
- `package main` just denotes that this file has an executable command which contains `func main()`. Then, you can run this code as: `go run main.go`. See [here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackageNames) for more info.
- You should rename your `func getValue()` in `functions` package to `func GetValue()`, because, only that way the func will be visible to other packages. See [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) for more info.

**File 1: main.go (located in MyProj/main.go)**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "MyProj/functions"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println(functions.GetValue())
}
```

**File 2: functions.go (located in MyProj/functions/functions.go)**

```
package functions

// `getValue` should be `GetValue` to be exposed to other packages.
// It should start with a capital letter.
func GetValue() string{
    return "Hello from this another package"
}
```

Comment: what if it's a method instead of a func?

Comment: @AvinashRaj A method belongs to a type, not to a package. Make the first letter of a method an uppercase letter. Then you can call it from another package using a value of its type. `t := time.Now()`, `t` is a `time.Time` value. You can call one of its methods like this: `t.Date()`. Date can be called from another package because it's `Date` not `date`. https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time

Comment: yep, let me explain my problem. I need to implement a method (having error 
 as receivable) to return the actual error message. ie. `err.ToString()` should return the custom response.

Comment: `func (err error)ToString string { return err.Error()}`. I have implemented this method on my own package but it's not working compalins about error is not in your package. we could modify this as func instead of method but curious to know

Comment: Your `err` type is not exported. You need to export it: `Err`. But you don't need to do it like that. Just implement the `error` interface: https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go

Answer (score 11):

Export function getValue by making 1st character of function name capital, GetValue

Answer (score 5):

In Go packages, all identifiers will be exported to other packages if the first letter of the identifier name **starts with an uppercase letter**.

=> change getValue() to GetValue()

Answer (score 5):

you can write

```
import(
  functions "./functions" 
)
func main(){
  c:= functions.getValue() <-
}
```

If you write in `gopath` write this import `functions "MyProj/functions"` or if you are working with Docker

Comment: This works great if you capitalize the first letter of the function to make it exported.

Answer (score 4):

- you need to create a `go.mod` file in the root directory of your project: `go mod init module_name`
- the name of exposed function should start with capital letter

```golang
    import(
       "module_name/functions" 
    )
    func main(){
      functions.SomeFunction()
    }
```