# cannot run aerospike go example

Tags: go, aerospike

I'm trying to run an aerospike go example:

```
package main

    import (
    "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
    "fmt"
    )

    func panicOnError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    }

     func main() {
    // define a client to connect to
    client, err := NewClient("127.0.0.1", 3000)
    panicOnError(err)

    key, err := NewKey("test", "aerospike", "key")
    panicOnError(err)

    // define some bins with data
    bins := BinMap{
        "bin1": 42,
        "bin2": "An elephant is a mouse with an operating system",
        "bin3": []interface{}{"Go", 2009},
    }

    // write the bins
    err = client.Put(nil, key, bins)
    panicOnError(err)

    // read it back!
    rec, err := client.Get(nil, key)
    panicOnError(err)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", *rec)

    // delete the key, and check if key exists
    existed, err := client.Delete(nil, key)
    panicOnError(err)
    fmt.Printf("Record existed before delete? %v\n", existed)
}
```

But I get an error:

```
Unresolved reference NewClient... 
and many more...
```

I've run the command:

```
go get github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go
```

and it has downloaded the package on the disk.

Can you help?

Answer (score 7):

You can see in the project [`aerospike/aerospike-client-go`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go) tests like [`example_listiter_int_test.go`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/95e1ad7791bdbca44707fedbb29be42024900d9c/example_listiter_int_test.go) which:

- import the project with:

  ```
  as "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
  ```
- use NewClient with the right prefix:

  ```
  var v as.Value = as.NewValue(myListInt([]int{1, 2, 3}))
  ```

So don't forget to prefix `NewClient`.

In your case:

```
import (
as "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
"fmt"
)
```

And:

```
client, err := as.NewClient("127.0.0.1", 3000)
```

`as` is an alias for the package name, since, as mentioned in "[Call a function from another package in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26142332/6309)":

> You import the package by its import path, and reference all its exported symbols (those starting with a capital letter) through the package name,

Since [`NewClient` is in `client.go`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/1dc8cf203d24cd454e71ce40ab4cd0bf3112df90/client.go) of the `package aerospike`, an alternative would be:

```
client, err := aerospike.NewClient("127.0.0.1", 3000)
```

Comment: @user8215502 During the compilation or the execution? If it is during the execution, then the original question has been resolved, and you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: during execution. i guess it's related to policy