# How to call package from a different package

Tags: go

I am trying to get a function from the package **ModelT** into my **Controllers** package . I have looked at the example on [Call a function from another package in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142074/call-a-function-from-another-package-in-go?rq=1) however it is not working. This is my simple code

```
package ModelT
 -- Print.go
 func PrintMe() string {

     return "hello"
 }



package Controllers
-- Circle.go
import ("Yislyapp/ModelT") -- This does not work 

  func Circle_List() {
ModelT.PrintMe()
}
```

My small program won't compile either saying: *can  not resolve directory yislyapp* . I get the samething even if I change it to *Yisly-Backend/ModelT* or *Yisly-Backend./ModelT* , it seems like it can't find the package. Any suggestions would be great since i'm starting out. If I put it into my Go file Home.go then it works

```
import (

    "./ModelT"
)
func main() {

         ModelT.PrintMe() -- This works in my Home.go file
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The tutorial [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `GOPATH` environment variable to the root of your Go project. Your source code should then be somewhere under `$GOPATH/src`. The import path for a package is the path to the package's directory relative to `$GOPATH/src`. See https://golang.org/doc/code.html for more info.